# When I float the div to the right the screen messes up...I've tried clear and some other options

Tags: css, html, css-float, footer

I'm having an issue in general when it comes to floats. I'll be doing fine with the layout but once I start floating the whole page does weird stuff. I think I need a better understanding of the concept of what goes on. Here is my code for html and css.

```css
* {
 margin: 0;
}
#heading {
 background-color: black;
 height: 150px;
}
#navigation {
 background-color: green;
 height: 30px;
}
#leftSide {
 background-color: blue;
 width: 400px;
 height: 700px;
}
#rightSide {
 background-color: red;
 width: 400px;
 height: 700px;
 float: right;
}
#footer {
 background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<body>
 <div id="wrapper">
 <div id="heading">Heading</div>
 <div id="navigation">Navigation</div>
 <div id="leftSide">Left Side</div>
 <div id="rightSide">Right Side</div>
 <div id="footer">Footer</div>
 <div style="clear: right;"></div>
 </div>
</body>
```

Comment: your footer goes up when you `float: right` on the `rightSide`.. is that the issue?

Comment: There is no question here. I vote to close it.

Answer (score 0):

Use `display:inline-block;` for your id `leftSide`

```css
#heading {
 background-color: black;
 height: 150px;
}
#navigation {
 background-color: green;
 height: 30px;
}
#leftSide {
 background-color: blue;
 width: 50%;
 height: 700px;
  display:inline-block;
}
#rightSide {
 background-color: red;
 width: 50%;
 height: 700px;
 float: right;
}
#footer {
 background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>This is it</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
 <div id="wrapper">
 <div id="heading">Heading</div>
 <div id="navigation">Navigation</div>
 <div id="leftSide">Left Side</div>
 <div id="rightSide">Right Side</div>
 <div id="footer">Footer</div>
 <div style="clear: right;"></div>
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

`Float`ing elements create a new `block formatting context` and so it must be `clear`ed before your `footer` if you expect it to come below the preceeding contents.

If I guess right, you need to `float: left` your `leftSide` div.

I placed your `clear: right` div above the footer and made it `clear: both`.

Snippet below:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
}
#heading {
  background-color: black;
  height: 150px;
}
#navigation {
  background-color: green;
  height: 30px;
}
#leftSide {
  background-color: blue;
  width: 400px;
  height: 700px;
  float: left;
}
#rightSide {
  background-color: red;
  width: 400px;
  height: 700px;
  float: right;
}
#footer {
  background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="wrapper">
    <div id="heading">Heading</div>
    <div id="navigation">Navigation</div>
    <div id="leftSide">Left Side</div>
    <div id="rightSide">Right Side</div>
    <div style="clear: both;"></div>
    <div id="footer">Footer</div>
  </div>
</body>
```