# Li float left, length dynamic : no border-bottom on the last row

Tags: html, css

here's the case:

https://jsfiddle.net/rpepf9xs/

I want to remove the border-bottom with selector: "nth-last-child()", however, if there are only 8 "li" in list, it goes wrong like this:

```css
ul {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0
}
li {
  display: block;
  width: 33%;
  height: 120px;
  float: left;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border-bottom: #666 1px solid;
  background: #fcc
}
li:nth-last-child(3),
li:nth-last-child(2),
li:last-child {
  border-bottom: 0px
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3</li>
  <li>4</li>
  <li>5</li>
  <li>6</li>
  <li>7</li>
  <li>8</li>
</ul>
```

Is there any way to fix this without javascript?

Thanks.

Comment: you should add `box-sizing: border-box;` to styles of `li`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add `clear:both` only `3n+1` element from the forth element. remove border for the li that is after the forth element from last

```css
ul {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0
}
li {
  display: block;
  width: 33%;
  height: 120px;
  float: left;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border-bottom: #666 1px solid;
  background: #fcc
}
li:nth-child(3n+1) {
  clear:both;
}
li:nth-last-child(4) ~ li:nth-child(3n+1), li:nth-last-child(4) ~ li:nth-child(3n+1) ~ li {
  border-bottom: 0px;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3</li>
  <li>4</li>
  <li>5</li>
  <li>6</li>
  <li>7</li>
  <li>8</li>
</ul>
```

This code will remove last row's border bottom no matter how many li you have

**Explaination:-**

`li:nth-last-child(4)` will be the forth element from last(border removal should start after this element).

So starting from `li:nth-last-child(4)` element we travel towards the `li:nth-child(3n+1)` element (which series like 4,7,10...)  and the border should not be there starts from this (`li:nth-child(3n+1)`) element. `~` is the successor siblings selector.

Comment: it will work fine even if you have any number of <LI>

Comment: Would you please explain how this selector works?  "li:nth-last-child(4) ~ li:nth-child(3n+1){   }"

Comment: why complex code when issue can be solved with one clear. no matter how many li you have it will always give the same result.

Comment: Wesleywai : I have added the explanation.
@Leothelion it will work even for any number of elements. it will also be helpful for some other in our community

Comment: @jafarbtech but my question is why to write that much code while we can simply do it, add clear:both after floated element(s). No need to add that much selector. got my point?

Comment: @Leothelion he wants "no border-bottom on the last row" so i have explained the way to do it even if he is going dynamic. simple

Answer (score 1):

Yes because you are missing `clear:both`. Whenever playing with float, don't forget to add clear:both or else it will give error of blank space if space is not settled in good way.

```css
ul {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0
}

li {
  display: block;
  width: 33%;
  height: 120px;
  float: left;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border-bottom: #666 1px solid;
  background: #fcc
}

li:nth-last-child(3),
li:nth-last-child(2),
li:last-child {
  border-bottom: 0px
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3</li>
  <li>4</li>
  <li>5</li>
  <li>6</li>
  <li>7</li>
  <li>8</li>
  <div style="clear:both;"></div>
</ul>
```

Comment: @Wesleywai doesn't it solve your problem? i thought this is the easiest answer.

Answer (score 0):

Just add `box-sizing: border-box` to `li` to solve the issue. And for the `border-bottom` issue you can link `nth-child`s and `nth-last-child`s:

```
li:nth-last-child(3):nth-child(3n+1),
li:nth-last-child(2):nth-child(3n+2),
li:nth-last-child(2):nth-child(3n+1),
li:last-child {
  border-bottom: 0px;
}
```

Also it would be good to *clear* the floats after its context (see a good [example here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39284594/when-i-float-the-div-to-the-right-the-screen-messes-up-ive-tried-clear-and-so/39286630#39286630)) using this:

```
ul:after{
  content:'';
  display:block;
  clear:both;
}
```

See demo below:

```css
ul {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

li {
  display: block;
  width: 33%;
  height: 120px;
  float: left;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border-bottom: #666 1px solid;
  background: #fcc;
  box-sizing:border-box;
}
li:nth-last-child(3):nth-child(3n+1),
li:nth-last-child(2):nth-child(3n+2),
li:nth-last-child(2):nth-child(3n+1),
li:last-child {
  border-bottom: 0px;
}

ul:after{
  content:'';
  display:block;
  clear:both;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3</li>
  <li>4</li>
  <li>5</li>
  <li>6</li>
  <li>7</li>
  <li>8</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Hi @kukkuz, I would like to keep border bottom of number 6

Comment: @Wesleywai check out the answer now and let me know, thanks! You can check it out by varying the `li` elements...

Comment: This change will make sure that whether there are 1,2 or 3 elements in the last row, they will not have the `border-bottom`