# DIV not fitting one inside the other as expected

Tags: html, css, css-float

I am faced with a CSS problem. The situation is as follow:

I have this kind of structure:

```css
#Block {
  background-color: #FF0000;
  padding-top: 30px;
  padding-bottom: 30px;
  padding-left: 30px;
  padding-right: 30px;
}
[class="Element"] {
  width: 33.33%;
  background-color: #0000FF;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<div id="Block">
  <div class="Element">
    Some contents.
  </div>
  <div class="Element">
    Some more contents.
  </div>
  <div class="Element">
    Still some more contents.
  </div>
</div>
```

I was expecting to see a red box behind my 3 elements(blue), containing them.

But I only see a red rectangle behind the elements, but with the wrong size, more precisely not high enough. It seems that the Block part is totally un related to the rest.

What did I do wrong?

Comment: I tried your code, and blue elements are inside of red box.

Comment: `[class="Element"]`? Don't do this. Use `.Element`

Answer (score 1):

Clear the *float*s using this:

```
#Block:after{
  content:'';
  display:block;
  clear:both;
}
```

and I guess that looks OK now.

**Why this happens?**

1. If the *containing blocks* have floating elements, then it will get height only if you *clear* the *floating context*.(See [an example here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39284594/when-i-float-the-div-to-the-right-the-screen-messes-up-ive-tried-clear-and-so/39286630#39286630))
2. If any one of them are not floated, then the *containing block* takes the height of this element.
3. You can also use `overflow: hidden` on the containing block to get the same effect.

```css
#Block {
  background-color: #FF0000;
  padding-top: 30px;
  padding-bottom: 30px;
  padding-left: 30px;
  padding-right: 30px;
}
[class="Element"] {
  width: 33.33%;
  background-color: #0000FF;
  float: left;
}
#Block:after{
  content:'';
  display:block;
  clear:both;
}
```

```html
<div id="Block">
  <div class="Element">
    Some contents.
  </div>
  <div class="Element">
    Some more contents.
  </div>
  <div class="Element">
    Still some more contents.
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: "**only** if you clear the floating context." — Untrue. There are [several other (nicer) ways](http://www.ejeliot.com/blog/59).

Comment: @Quentin and that is a very old article too (10yrs back)... Let me know if you are pointing out at something that I may have missed ?

Comment: You can also use the `overflow` property to fix this issue...

Comment: @Stuart my answer already mentions it...

Comment: @kukkuz yes i know... (!?) ...my comment was based on these comments here requesting nicer ways. It doesnt matter....

Comment: @Stuart ok, thanks :)